# Grouping or adding classes to CCK form fields

Tags: 7, forms

I'm looking for a way to group sections of my CCK add/edit forms so that I can give users a form with sections instead of one long page. I'm already using Fieldgroup to group fields for display so what I'm looking for is something similar for grouping fields for editing.

I realize I can do this with large amounts of CSS, jQuery or adding custom templates but I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: You can use fieldgroup on the node edit form as well. Look just below "add existing field" and you will see "add new group"

Comment: Wow, I missed that one. @NigelWaters, if you want to add this as an answer I'll mark it as correct, although most people likely will know about this, I'm sure there will be others in future that will miss it and hopefully google their way here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fieldgroup on the node edit form as well. Look just below "add existing field" and you will see "add new group"